# How to send dynamic update to DNS Server using Avahi?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, dynamic, avahi, name

I am using beaglebone running avahi-daemon and I have configure it to respond mdns query with local name “myboard.local” when accessed from PC on same network. It works fine.

But, how can I configure Avahi to send dynamic update message to DNS server so that DNS server will add an entry of “myboard.local” into its caching table ? The reason is some of the PC machines runs windows7 and they only query on standard dns query message.

Or Do I need to use some other utility for this purpose? Any suggestions will be helpful.